# What's wrong? | MySQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Trying to write stored function for checking is account verified or not. I want to use it in view.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `Admin_Departaments` AS
    SELECT 
        `Departaments`.`Id` AS `Id`,
        `Departaments`.`Name` AS `Name`,
        `Departaments`.`Email` AS `Email`,
        ST_ISEMPTY(`Departaments`.`EmailVerificationToken`) AS `IsVerified`
    FROM
        `Departaments`
```

Following show errors and code statements.

> ERROR 1227: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER
>   privilege(s) for this operation

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`%`@`%` FUNCTION `IsEmpty`(str tinytext) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
IF str = '' THEN
RETURN true;
else Return false;
END IF;
END
```

> ERROR 1418: This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS
>   SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you might
>   want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `IsEmpty`(str tinytext) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
IF str = '' THEN
RETURN true;
else Return false;
END IF;
END
```

> ERROR 1419: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is
>   enabled (you might want to use the less safe
>   log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

SQL Statement:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `IsEmpty`(str tinytext) RETURNS tinyint(1)
deterministic
BEGIN
IF str = '' THEN
RETURN true;
else Return false;
END IF;
END
```

Some more info:
 
-Database is stored in Google Cloud Platform
-Root user is the main user that given from Google
-I already tried to change root privileges from gcloud shell running mysql from sudo, but got [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ3m1.png)
-The root privileges are all besides FILE. Role is all besides DBA.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y34em.png)

Comment: Please describe the nature of the problem in the title, not that you have a problem. That much is implied as you're posting on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation [Cloud SQL FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq)

> Cloud SQL does not support SUPER privileges

A viable solution here is to [set up MySQL instance on a Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql). Doing that you will be able to have SUPER USER privileges on your instance and you will overcome this errors.

Comment: Ok, but how can I get around this problem?